# Specific parsing XML into an array

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

So if I have XML that looks something like this....

```
<people>
    <person>
        <name>a</name>
    </person>
    <person>
        <name>b</name>
    </person>
</people>
```

What's the best/easiest way to parse this into a C# array called 'people' where people[0] is the first person object, and then how would it be formatted and how would I go about accessing it?

Thanks!

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: A good place to start would be http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387067.aspx

Comment: You can use either XmlReader or Linq to Xml or XmlSerialization - now you can do some reading and come back with specific questions

Comment: @JimMischel the example in the article you pointed to is so baaad - especially for beginners. You can do the same without aggregates just by doing this `Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(root.DescendantNodes().OfType<XText>()));` - much simpler and probably much faster.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [LINQ-To-Xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) to load this file into an array.

To simply handle the object after loading them you could create a class representing a person:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then load the file using the [`XElement.Load`-method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.load.aspx):

```
var document = XElement.Load("persons.xml");
var persons = document.Elements("Person")
    .Select(p => new Person{ Name = p.Element("Name").Value }
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: In all of these answers I'm getting an error that it doesn't contain a definition for the Select method, which is strange... Why?

Answer (score 2):

My C# is rusty, but this is simple enough using **XML serialization**

Deserializing (reading), modifying, then serializing (writing):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

    [XmlRoot("people")]
    public class People
    {
        [XmlElement("person")]
        public Person[] person { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Person
    {
        [XmlElement("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            People people = null;
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(People));
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("people.xml"))
            {
                people = (People)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }
            people.person[0].Name = "Dan";
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("people.xml"))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, people);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I keep getting this error no matter which solution I use: System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' could be found

Comment: Then you didn't try this one as it doesn't use LINQ

Comment: Not sure but you probably need `using System.Xml.Linq;`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily with **LinqToXml**:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(myXmlString); // .Load("filepath");
var persons = doc.Root
                 .Elements("Person")
                 .Select(x=> new Person {Name= x.Element("Name").Value})
                 .ToArray();
```

It will return you an array of `Person`'s defined as below.

**Person**

```
public class Person{
     public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then (query syntax):

```
var arr = (from p in XDocument.Load(path) // or .Parse(str)
                              .Root
                              .Elements("person")
           select new Person
           {
               Name = (string)p.Attribute("name")
           }).ToArray();
```

The same in Extension Methods syntax:

```
XDocument.Load(path)
         .Root
         .Elements("person")
         .Select(p => new new Person
             {
                 Name = (string)p.Attribute("name")
             })
         .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(input);
string[] names = doc.Root.Descendants("name").Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();
```

If the input xml format is as simple as the one you provided the above statement is sufficient, otherwise add this where clause to not capture other `name` elements in your xml file:

```
string[] names = doc.Root.Descendants("name")
                        .Where(x => x.Parent.Name == "person")
                        .Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

One line is enough.

```
var people=XDocument.Load(path).Root.Elements().Select(y => y.Elements().ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.Value)).ToArray();
```

You need to specify following namespaces for testing

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
```

test code

```
var path=@"c:\people.xml";
var people=XDocument.Load(path).Root.Elements().Select(y => y.Elements().ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.Value)).ToArray();

foreach(var person in people) {
    Console.WriteLine("name = {0}", person["name"]);
    Console.WriteLine("name = {0}", person["age"]); // requires person have a age defined in your xml file
}
```

the sample xml for test

```
<people>
    <person>
        <name>Humbert Humbert</name>
        <age>36</age>
    </person>

    <person>
        <name>Lolita</name>
        <age>12</age>
    </person>
</people>
```

Comment: This looks like the best one to use but I can't solve my error where it says Select is not a defined method.