# Using XElement to parse this XML into an array

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

Let's say I have a Person class:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

How do I parse an XML file containing

```
<person>
    <name>a</name>
</person>
<person>
    <name>b</name>
</person>
```

into an array of two `Person`s?

This is a variant of this question: [Specific parsing XML into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14740382/specific-parsing-xml-into-an-array)

The only difference is that there is no `<people></people>` surrounding the whole XML. The `<person>`s start immediately.

Comment: If there is no outer root tag, then it is invalid xml by definition.  You'd have to parse it yourself, or modify the string to make it valid.

Comment: If there is no outer root tag then it is an invalid xml like @Jonesopolis said

Comment: This "XML" is invalid, see https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-root.  But if you need to load it into an XDocument anyway, see [C# XDocument Load with multiple roots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18186225/c-sharp-xdocument-load-with-multiple-roots).  Or do you really need to deserialize to `List<Person>` and not load into an `XElement`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = 
                "<person>" +
                    "<name>a</name>" +
                "</person>" +
                "<person>" +
                    "<name>b</name>" +
                "</person>";
            xml = "<Root>" + xml + "</Root>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            List<Person> people = doc.Descendants("person").Select(x => new Person() {
                Name = (string)x.Element("name")
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```